# Print out all usernames in a Razor Page with .net core Identity

Tags: asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.0, razor-pages

I'm new to Razor Pages and Identity and can't find out how i print out all usernames on a page. 
I get that in the page i probably write something like `@model.username`, but i can't figure out what to write in the PageModel.

I'm using .net core 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a little vague, but it sounds like you're trying to get a list of all usernames in the system, and you're likely stumbling on `UserManager` providing no functionality to return multiple users.

`UserManager` is just a wrapper around your context that makes doing some user-related tasks easier/more fluid. You can always just drop-down to use the context directly, though. Simply, if you're not already, you'll need to inject your context into your page. Then, to get the list of usernames you can do:

```
await _context.Users.Select(x => x.UserName).ToListAsync();
```

Store that in some property on your page model, and you're off to the races.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but i dont really understand what to do. I understand that in the page i need to do a foreach loop, but i can't acces the list from the page model. My page model is currently: 
`public async void OnGetAsync()
        {
            var allUsers = await _context.Users.Select(u => u.UserName).ToListAsync();            

        }`

Comment: I got it now. I used `public List<string> GetUsers { get; set; ` and then stored the list in GetUsers in the `OnGetAsync()` function. Thanks for the help!